# Python 3 : Easier way to call other file's variables?

Tags: python, import, python-import

A very simple question, in my program i use:

```
import resources
```

`resources.py` is a file were i load all my assets
and then i must write :

```
example = resources.image1
```

if i load my image in the main file i just write :

```
example = image1
```

My question is : is there a simple way to avoid writing each time `example = resources.image1`, so just write `example = image1`

Comment: `from resources import image1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
from resources import *
```

Should make

```
example = image1
```

work just fine.
However, as someone commented, this isn’t the best method. It makes it a nightmare to work out what libraries everything came from, and the code becomes harder to understand. Another way to reduce typing is:

```
import resources as r
```

This will allow you to type:

```
example = r.image1
```

If you only want to access `image1`, then you can just do:

```
from resources import image1
example=image1
```

Comment: You shouldn't use wildcard imports if you want to comply with PEP 8: https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: I agree, but wildcard imports answered the question. Answering the question should take priority over advice and explanation.

Comment: A better answer would have been: `from resources import image1`  That answers the question and is correct code.

Comment: @chrisz I know, but you already gave that answer as a comment to the question. I’m not sure why you didn’t give it as an answer, but there is no point giving duplicate answers without any extra explanation.

Comment: Then maybe no point in answering at all :)